# Read file containing PHP without parsing PHP

Tags: php, html, xhtml, textarea, fckeditor

I am using a wysiwyg editor in a web app. It is FCKeditor. In order to edit a file, other than loading javascript, my web form that edits the the file looks like this:

```
<textarea><?php include('myWebDoc.html') ?></textarea>
```

I also tried this:

```
<textarea><?php file_get_contents('myWebDoc.html') ?></textarea>
```

Both attempts end up parsing the php inside the web document before it gets to the editor.

Is there a better php function or way to get the contents of a file into the textarea tag without parsing?

Comment: You might want to consider using javascript to load the file into the textarea after the page loads. If it still doesn't work, you could take a look at FCKeditor docs and see if it provides a way to set the contents of the editor directly. Or, if switching editors is a possibility, NicEdit is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `readfile` instead of `file_get_contents`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Comment: He doesn't want to read it into a string, though, he wants to output the contents to the buffer. This means the file could be streamed instead of allocating all the memory for the string and then outputting that. In other words, if anything performance should be better, not worse.

Comment: I have my doubts, still `readfile()` doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: readfile solves the problem of the omitted echo. Care to expound on your 'doubts?'

Comment: I ran 4 tests:
include() parsed the php prior to bringing it in - not what I wanted
readfile() and file_get_contents() brought the php in without parsing and also retained the script in tact -- that's what I do want
htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents()) converts all < and > to &lt; and &gt: -- which is not what I want

So I got what I need out of readfile() and file_get_contents() even though I didnt think I was getting it prior to seeking help here.

Bottom line, I need the editor to accept the readfile() or file_get_contents() results and handle appropriately -- so it is an editor issue now.

Comment: @Dr. DOT: What's wrong with `&lt;` and `>` inside the textarea? That's correctly formed HTML and would be exactly the result produced if you manually typed `<` and `>` inside it.

Comment: Alix, this is a server-to-client back to server process. In other words, I am taking the raw contents of a web doc on the server (that contains properly coded php syntax) and bringing it into a JavaScript wysiwyg text editor (FCKEditor similar to TinyMCE).

I need to be able to use the text editor to edit the web doc and then have it save back to the server in a parsible & downloaded form that the php parsing engine on the server can handle as well as the browser on the client.

Comment: So, if I let the text editor translate <?php into &lt;?php and save it back to the server in that form -- then the server will no longer parse my php.

IMO that's what's wrong

Comment: Do not use `readfile()`; it *will* break your HTML. @H.Ferrence misunderstood escaping, the data does not get sent back to the server in its escaped form.

Answer (score 4):

The correct form should be something like this:

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.html')); ?></textarea>
```

Depending on the contents of the HTML file you might also want to try `htmlentities()`.

Comment: -1 for -1ing me one and for not using readfile instead of file_get_contents for outputting a file straight to the buffer. ;)

Comment: @no: I'm not getting into a micro optimization discussion here, I still believe `file_get_contents()` is probably faster but that isn't the issue. `readfile()` will output directly to the browser, that means it will break the HTML if the file has any HTML special char. That was the reason for my down vote (and for not using `htmlspecialchars()` at all), got it?

Comment: @Dr. DOT: Could you share the contents of the HTML file? Regarding your comment on @no answer: you should **definitely** use `htmlspecialchars()` (or similar, like `htmlentities()`), otherwise it can break your HTML.

Comment: Alix, readfile will output directly to the current buffer, not necessarily the browser. I never said not to use htmlspecialchars or similar. An output buffer callback could easily be used to process the text before insertion if necessary. And it's not necessarily necessary... It should only screw up if the inserted file contains a closing `</textarea>` tag. He's editing a document; chances are there's no `</textarea>` in the document, and for all I know FCKeditor will not treat escaped HTML as HTML at all (see comment from OP on my answer).

Comment: @no: I'm sorry but IMHO the OP is wrong. `htmlspecialchars()` should always be used when displaying (XML, HTML, PHP, whatever) tags inside another tag (in this case a textarea). Now, upon submission he may or may not want to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` - but that's another question. Your answer didn't cover this at all, and certainly didn't provide a **solution**. I've my doubts if `readfile()` is faster than `file_get_contents()` - probably consumes less memory. To be continued...

Comment: @no: But I rather do `echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('file.html'));` than do `ob_start(); readfile('file.html'); echo htmlspecialchars(ob_get_clean());` - if I got your suggestion right! Anyway, this is pointless and the OP probably doesn't care so I'll stop wasting my time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the textarea and just have it read normally, use pre tags:

```
<pre>
<?php 
    echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('test2.php'));
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might possibly work:

```
<textarea><?php readfile('myWebDoc.html'); ?></textarea>
```

But I think you might have to escape the HTML to make it work properly - I don't know for sure:

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('myWebDoc.html')); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: You **do** have to escape HTML.